# Why does requesting JSONAPI metadata from a Spring Data Rest repository return a recursive result in some cases?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I have a simple Spring Boot/Spring Data Rest test application with a single entity "Contact" and a single CRUDRepository. There is no other code.

When the database is empty, requesting the api+json metadata on /contact works properly:

```
$ curl -s 'http://localhost:8080/contacts' \
    -H 'Accept: application/vnd.api+json'\ 
    -H 'Content-Type: application/hal+json'
```

...produces:

```
{
  "links" : [ {
    "rel" : "self",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/contacts"
  }, {
    "rel" : "profile",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/contacts"
  } ],
  "content" : [ {
    "relTargetType" : "sdr.Contact",
    "collectionValue" : true,
    "rel" : null,
    "value" : [ ]
  } ]
}
```

However, when I put a single contact in the database, the same request produces a massive recursive dump of information:

```
{
  "links" : [ {
    "rel" : "self",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/contacts"
  }, {
    "rel" : "profile",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/contacts"
  } ],
  "content" : [ {
    "id" : 2,
    "firstName" : "Test",
    "lastName" : "Contact",
    "embeddeds" : {
      "content" : [ ]
    },
    "propertyAccessor" : {
      "bean" : {
        "id" : 2,
        "firstName" : "Test",
        "lastName" : "Contact"
      }
    },
    "persistentEntity" : {
      "idProperty" : {
        "name" : "id",
        "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
        "field" : {
          "name" : "id",
          "type" : "java.lang.Long",
          "modifiers" : 2,
          "annotations" : [ ],
          "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
          "synthetic" : false,
          "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
          "enumConstant" : false,
          "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
          "annotatedType" : {
            "type" : "java.lang.Long",
            "annotations" : [ ],
            "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
          },
          "accessible" : true
        },
        "association" : false,
        "owner" : {
          "idProperty" : {
            "name" : "id",
            "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
            "field" : {
              "name" : "id",
              "type" : "java.lang.Long",
              "modifiers" : 2,
              "annotations" : [ ],
              "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
              "synthetic" : false,
              "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
              "enumConstant" : false,
              "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
              "annotatedType" : {
                "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                "annotations" : [ ],
                "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
              },
              "accessible" : true
            },
            "association" : false,
            "owner" : {
              "idProperty" : {
                "name" : "id",
                "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                "field" : {
                  "name" : "id",
                  "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                  "modifiers" : 2,
                  "annotations" : [ ],
                  "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                  "synthetic" : false,
                  "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                  "enumConstant" : false,
                  "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                  "annotatedType" : {
                    "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                    "annotations" : [ ],
                    "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                  },
                  "accessible" : true
                },
                "association" : false,
                "owner" : {
                  "idProperty" : {
                    "name" : "id",
                    "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                    "field" : {
                      "name" : "id",
                      "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                      "modifiers" : 2,
                      "annotations" : [ ],
                      "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                      "synthetic" : false,
                      "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                      "enumConstant" : false,
                      "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                      "annotatedType" : {
                        "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                        "annotations" : [ ],
                        "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                      },
                      "accessible" : true
                    },
                    "association" : false,
                    "owner" : {
                      "idProperty" : {
                        "name" : "id",
                        "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                        "field" : {
                          "name" : "id",
                          "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                          "modifiers" : 2,
                          "annotations" : [ ],
                          "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                          "synthetic" : false,
                          "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                          "enumConstant" : false,
                          "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                          "annotatedType" : {
                            "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                            "annotations" : [ ],
                            "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                          },
                          "accessible" : true
                        },
                        "association" : false,
                        "owner" : {
                          "idProperty" : {
                            "name" : "id",
                            "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                            "field" : {
                              "name" : "id",
                              "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                              "modifiers" : 2,
                              "annotations" : [ ],
                              "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                              "synthetic" : false,
                              "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                              "enumConstant" : false,
                              "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                              "annotatedType" : {
                                "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                "annotations" : [ ],
                                "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                              },
                              "accessible" : true
                            },
                            "association" : false,
                            "owner" : {
                              "idProperty" : {
                                "name" : "id",
                                "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                "field" : {
                                  "name" : "id",
                                  "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                  "modifiers" : 2,
                                  "annotations" : [ ],
                                  "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                                  "synthetic" : false,
                                  "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                                  "enumConstant" : false,
                                  "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                  "annotatedType" : {
                                    "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                    "annotations" : [ ],
                                    "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                                  },
                                  "accessible" : true
                                },
                                "association" : false,
                                "owner" : {
                                  "idProperty" : {
                                    "name" : "id",
                                    "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                    "field" : {
                                      "name" : "id",
                                      "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                      "modifiers" : 2,
                                      "annotations" : [ ],
                                      "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                                      "synthetic" : false,
                                      "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                                      "enumConstant" : false,
                                      "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                      "annotatedType" : {
                                        "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                        "annotations" : [ ],
                                        "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                                      },
                                      "accessible" : true
                                    },
                                    "association" : false,
                                    "owner" : {
                                      "idProperty" : {
                                        "name" : "id",
                                        "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                        "field" : {
                                          "name" : "id",
                                          "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                          "modifiers" : 2,
                                          "annotations" : [ ],
                                          "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                                          "synthetic" : false,
                                          "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                                          "enumConstant" : false,
                                          "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                          "annotatedType" : {
                                            "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                            "annotations" : [ ],
                                            "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                                          },
                                          "accessible" : true
                                        },
                                        "association" : false,
                                        "owner" : {
                                          "idProperty" : {
                                            "name" : "id",
                                            "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                            "field" : {
                                              "name" : "id",
                                              "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                              "modifiers" : 2,
                                              "annotations" : [ ],
                                              "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                                              "synthetic" : false,
                                              "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                                              "enumConstant" : false,
                                              "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                              "annotatedType" : {
                                                "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                "annotations" : [ ],
                                                "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                                              },
                                              "accessible" : true
                                            },
                                            "association" : false,
                                            "owner" : {
                                              "idProperty" : {
                                                "name" : "id",
                                                "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                "field" : {
                                                  "name" : "id",
                                                  "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                  "modifiers" : 2,
                                                  "annotations" : [ ],
                                                  "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                                                  "synthetic" : false,
                                                  "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                                                  "enumConstant" : false,
                                                  "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                  "annotatedType" : {
                                                    "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                    "annotations" : [ ],
                                                    "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                                                  },
                                                  "accessible" : true
                                                },
                                                "association" : false,
                                                "owner" : {
                                                  "idProperty" : {
                                                    "name" : "id",
                                                    "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                    "field" : {
                                                      "name" : "id",
                                                      "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                      "modifiers" : 2,
                                                      "annotations" : [ ],
                                                      "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                                                      "synthetic" : false,
                                                      "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                                                      "enumConstant" : false,
                                                      "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                      "annotatedType" : {
                                                        "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                        "annotations" : [ ],
                                                        "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                                                      },
                                                      "accessible" : true
                                                    },
                                                    "association" : false,
                                                    "owner" : {
                                                      "idProperty" : {
                                                        "name" : "id",
                                                        "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                        "field" : {
                                                          "name" : "id",
                                                          "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                          "modifiers" : 2,
                                                          "annotations" : [ ],
                                                          "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                                                          "synthetic" : false,
                                                          "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                                                          "enumConstant" : false,
                                                          "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                          "annotatedType" : {
                                                            "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                            "annotations" : [ ],
                                                            "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                                                          },
                                                          "accessible" : true
                                                        },
                                                        "association" : false,
                                                        "owner" : {
                                                          "idProperty" : {
                                                            "name" : "id",
                                                            "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                            "field" : {
                                                              "name" : "id",
                                                              "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                              "modifiers" : 2,
                                                              "annotations" : [ ],
                                                              "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                                                              "synthetic" : false,
                                                              "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                                                              "enumConstant" : false,
                                                              "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                              "annotatedType" : {
                                                                "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                                "annotations" : [ ],
                                                                "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                                                              },
                                                              "accessible" : true
                                                            },
                                                            "association" : false,
                                                            "owner" : {
                                                              "idProperty" : {
                                                                "name" : "id",
                                                                "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                                "field" : {
                                                                  "name" : "id",
                                                                  "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                                  "modifiers" : 2,
                                                                  "annotations" : [ ],
                                                                  "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                                                                  "synthetic" : false,
                                                                  "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                                                                  "enumConstant" : false,
                                                                  "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                                  "annotatedType" : {
                                                                    "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                                    "annotations" : [ ],
                                                                    "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                                                                  },
                                                                  "accessible" : true
                                                                },
                                                                "association" : false,
                                                                "owner" : {
                                                                  "idProperty" : {
                                                                    "name" : "id",
                                                                    "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                                    "field" : {
                                                                      "name" : "id",
                                                                      "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                                      "modifiers" : 2,
                                                                      "annotations" : [ ],
                                                                      "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                                                                      "synthetic" : false,
                                                                      "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                                                                      "enumConstant" : false,
                                                                      "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                                      "annotatedType" : {
                                                                        "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                                        "annotations" : [ ],
                                                                        "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                                                                      },
                                                                      "accessible" : true
                                                                    },
                                                                    "association" : false,
                                                                    "owner" : {
                                                                      "idProperty" : {
                                                                        "name" : "id",
                                                                        "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                                        "field" : {
                                                                          "name" : "id",
                                                                          "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                                          "modifiers" : 2,
                                                                          "annotations" : [ ],
                                                                          "declaredAnnotations" : [ ],
                                                                          "synthetic" : false,
                                                                          "declaringClass" : "sdr.Contact",
                                                                          "enumConstant" : false,
                                                                          "genericType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                                          "annotatedType" : {
                                                                            "type" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                                            "annotations" : [ ],
                                                                            "declaredAnnotations" : [ ]
                                                                          },
                                                                          "accessible" : true
                                                                        },
                                                                        "association" : false,
                                                                        "owner" : {
                                                                          "idProperty" : {
                                                                            "name" : "id",
                                                                            "rawType" : "java.lang.Long",
                                                                            "field" : {
                                                                              "name" : "id",

 ***SNIP, THIS GOES ON FOREVER ***
```

**Why is this recursive result returned? Is this expected behavior?**

Everything else works normally. There are no JPA relationships or any other complicating factors in the test application. I am able to use the HAL Browser to add and remove records, etc.

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.2 and Spring Data Rest 2.4.2.

Here's the sole entity in the application:

```
@Entity
public class Contact {

    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Contact() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Basic
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface ContactRepository extends CrudRepository<Contact, Long> {
}
```

That's the entirety of the code in the app.

*UPDATE: This appears to be a bug in Spring Data REST. See [DATAREST-767](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-767) for a test application. Also may be related to [DATAREST-733](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-733) and [DATAREST-734](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-734)*

Answer (score 0):

There's no support in Spring Data REST for JSON API, what you get is the default representation rendered for `+json`.